# transformer voltage analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, mutual-inductance

I'm trying to figure out the voltage and current (and subsequently power) of the resistor R2 in this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs5MzD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit is in resonance and the inductors are lined with a coupling coefficient of 0,9.

From my understanding of mutual inductance I get the following KVL equations:
$$ -V_{in} R_1 I_1 + (j\omega L -j\omega L)I_1 + j\omega kLnI_2 = 0 $$
$$ R_2 I_1 + j\omega L n^2 I_2 + j\omega kLnI_1 = 0 $$

Solving for I2 I get:
$$ I_2 = \frac{-j\omega kLn V_{in}}{R_2 + \frac{\omega^2k^2L^2n^2}{R_1} + j\omega Ln^2 } $$

However when I compare this to simulations in LTspice (with a timestep of 0.1ns) it differs quite a lot (with around 10% if not more), so I am very unsure if this is correct.
I have taken the absolute value of I2 as the amplitude of the wave.
Does anyone know what is wrong here? Or are simulation programs not exact? :S

Comment: Are you allowing the LTspice simulation to run long enough that it reaches steady state? There will be transient effects at t=0.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Yes, I am simulating it for 10 ms, the transient effects disappear after about 1 ms (there is a very distinct wobbly effect in the beginning).

Comment: There something in the back of my mind that says that LTspice likes to add a small default series resistance for inductors. Can you verify that this is not the case for your simulation? You could remove the capacitor, run an operating point analysis, and verify that the inductor voltage is zero.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I had left them blank, but now I manually set them all to zero. The odd thing is that if I increase N dramatically (say to 100) then I get wildly different answers. Using the formula I get 6 kV, using LTsplice I get around 1.5 kV :S Feels like it's more than just some small added resistance :S

Comment: Can you show your simulation circuit diagram?

Comment: Here's a picture of it if it helps [link](https://imgur.com/a/2RvyulE)
This is for a value of n = 2, thus L2 = 4

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Appears I did a big Whoopsie, I both forgot to multiply the frequency by 2pi to get the angular frequency and I had too low of a step size in the simulation. By pure luck these two mistakes just so happened to almost cancel each other out in the interval I was looking at. Thank's for your time tho :) Should I delete this question? :s

Comment: You have no grounding on the secondary side. At the very least, you should add a `1meg` resistor, or higher, to ground, then do a differential probing for your secondary voltage. Also, what @ElliotAlderson says about series resistances, they are, by default, `1m` for inductors, *unless they are coupled*, then it's zero. However, in your case, you already have a series resistance elsewhere, so it's fine.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Tried that now, didn't make a difference tho but thank's for the suggestion :) I've managed to find the source of the error (too big time step). Should I keep this post up for others to find or should I delete it so that it doesn't take up search space for others looking for more useful questions?

Comment: @BeaconofWierd How did you manage to simulate it, it should and it does complain of floating nodes. Maybe you have some other settings, like `gshunt`, or `cshunt`, set elsewhere. Try reverting your settings to their defaults, if this happened, who knows how else they might influence the results? (particularly with `25p` in there). An admin is better suited to answer that -- if that happens, you'll see a message about it.

Comment: Also, it's best if you don't make this a reflex: blaming the tool instead of the user handling it. Millions of users vouch for its exactness. ;-)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I was actually thinking my hand calculations were off and the tool was right, not that the tool was wrong :p But you're right about the warnings, they pop up after it's done simulating, I guess I must have either had a ground there before or simply not noticed the pop-up warning somehow :S